# Дополнительное условие в скрипте на PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица

```
-----------------
|   А   |   B   |
-----------------
|   2   |   1   |
|   3   |   4   |
|   2   | null  |
|   3   |   4   |
|   2   |   6   |
|   4   |   4   |
-----------------
```

Задача - удалить дубликаты по столбцу А, взяв в результат последнее значение по столбцу В, но если среди значений В есть null, то оставить именно эту строку, удалив остальные. Без учета условия с null получилось бы что-то вроде:

```
for cdup in (select А, max(rowid) as rd
  from table
    group by А
    having count(1) > 1) loop
  delete from table where rowid <> cdup.rd;
end loop;
```

Но тогда строка с null может удалиться, а мы хотим её оставить. Как бы элегантнее составить скрипт?

Comment: *взяв в результат последнее значение по столбцу В* Последнее - при сортировке по какому признаку?

Comment: Не имеет значения, поэтому здесь так и поэтому чуть ниже использовался фразу _null **может** удалиться_. Имеет значение только если есть Null.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов если нет `null` значения, то какое в колонке B должно остаться?

Comment: @Viktorov любое, как повезет. Я использовал max(rowid) сугубо чтобы определиться с конкретным, но на самом деле это не так важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это список строк, которые будут удалены. Проверьте, сойдет или нет:

```
with t (a, b) as (
          select 2, 1 from dual union all
          select 3, 4 from dual union all
          select 2, null from dual union all
          select 3, 4 from dual union all
          select 2, 6 from dual union all
          select 4, 4 from dual)
select a, b
  from (select a, b, row_number() over (partition by a order by b desc nulls first) rn 
          from t)
 where rn > 1

     A          B
---------- ----------
     2          6 
     2          1 
     3          4
```

Ну а дальше просто:

```
delete from t where (a, b) in (
    select a, b
      from (select a, b, row_number() over (partition by a order by b desc nulls first) rn 
              from t)
     where rn > 1)
```

У вас никакого первичного ключа не указано, я написал запрос исходя из того, что первичный ключ - это пара `(a, b)`.

Comment: Примеряю к своей реальной ситуации. В качестве первичного ключа я использую rowid.

Comment: Тогда его можно подставить в запрос вместо `(a, b)`